# Converting hierarchical text to json object

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, converters

I need to write a simple compiler for a project. The purpose of this is that I need to convert this file from a shape that can be easily readable/editable by a human to a JSON object.

I am adding what I want to achieve by adding a simple working example below.
The Input File:

```
define character:
  asomeone1:
    name: A Someone 1
    age: 17
  asomeone2:
    name: A Someone 2
    age: 20
  asomeone3:
    name: A Someone 3
    age: 11
  asomeone4:
    name: A Someone 4
    age: 23

define events:
  start:
    event emit 'birthday' on asomeone1
    start dialogue 'Blah blah blah' as asomeone2
```

The Defination:

```
export const AllowedPropsWithDepth: {
  [index: number]: {
    parent: string;
    type: string;
    names: string[];
    default: any[];
    apply: any[];
  }[];
} = {
  0: [
    {
      parent: 'define',
      type: 'define $0',
      names: ['name'],
      default: ['default'],
      apply: [/* a class or a function */ Defination]
    },
    {
      parent: 'label',
      type: 'label $0',
      names: ['name'],
      default: ['default'],
      apply: [/* a class or a function */ EventLabel]
    },
  ],
};
```

Excepted Output:

```js
{
  "definations": [
    {
      "name": "character",
      "values": {
        "asomeone1": { "name": "A Someone 1", "age": "17" },
        "asomeone2": { "name": "A Someone 2", "age": "20" },
        // ...
    }
  ],
  "labels": [
    {
      "name": "start",
      "value": `event emit 'birthday' on asomeone1
                start dialogue 'Blah blah blah' as asomeone2`
    }
  ]
}
```

Constants

```
export const NEW_LINE = /\r?\n/;
export const SPACE_DEPTH = /\S|$/;
```

Main code:

```js
// ...

import Chunk from './Chunk.js';
import * as Constants from './constants.js';

// ...

const FILE_DIRECTORY = PATH.join(__dirname, '../src', READ_FILE);

// ...

const Result = FS.readFileSync(FILE_DIRECTORY, 'utf-8');

// My first try with a big failure
const ValueMap = Result.split(Constants.NEW_LINE);

const Memo = [];

let DepthMemory: {
  Depth: number;
  LineIndex: number;
}[] = [];

ValueMap.forEach((v, index) => {
  if (v == '') return;
  const Depth: number = Math.floor(v.search(Constants.SPACE_DEPTH) / 2) * 2;
  const Parent = DepthMemory.filter((v) => {
    return v.Depth == Depth - 2;
  }).at(-1);
  if (Parent == undefined) {
    DepthMemory.push({
      Depth,
      LineIndex: index,
    });
    return;
  }
});
```

## For the second attempt with class

'Chunk' class file

```
// ...

export default class Chunk {
  Raw: string;
  RawParsed: string[];

  constructor(Raw: string) {
    this.Raw = Raw;
    this.RawParsed = this.Raw.split(Constants.NEW_LINE);

    const GroupMemory: { [index: string | number]: any } = {};

    this.RawParsed.forEach((parsedLine: string) => {
      // Get length of tab count on string start
      const Depth: number = Math.floor(
        parsedLine.search(Constants.SPACE_DEPTH) / 2
      );

      // Try find props or return default value
      const Props = Constants.AllowedPropsWithDepth[Depth] || [];

      // remove spaces from string
      const self: String = parsedLine.trimStart();

      // Try match this string with props
      const Match = Props.findIndex((Prop) => {
        return self.startsWith(Prop.parent);
      });
      // If cannot find any match, destory this state and skip to next state
      if (Match < 0) return null;

      // Save matched prop.
      const MatchedProp = Props[Match];

      // parse type and current string
      const Matcher = MatchedProp.type.split(' ');
      const Matching = self.split(' ');

      // For every word in current, try run a function
      Matching.forEach((Element: string, index: number) => {
        // Find default in type string
        const check = Matcher[index];

        // If it is not a variable, we can return
        if (!check.startsWith('$')) return;

        const MatchIndex = parseInt(check.split('$').slice(1).join(''));

        // Add result to memory
        GroupMemory[MatchedProp.names[MatchIndex]] =
          (Element.endsWith(':') ? Element.slice(0, -1) : Element) ||
          MatchedProp.default[MatchIndex] ||
          undefined;
        console.log(GroupMemory);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Main Code:

```js
const ChunkMap = Result.split(/\r?\n\r?\n/g);
ChunkMap.forEach(chunk => new Chunk(chunk));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.  Could you please [edit] to add the requested output?

Comment: That helps a lot.  I still have some confusion.  I don't really understand your `AllowedPropsWithDepth` definition or how it relates to the relationship between input and output.  And it's not clear how "events" turns into "labels" or why the first "define" ends up in "defintions" but the second one doesn't.  Are these fixed requirements, or are you still working through them?

Comment: I writed out what will happen with the final version of the code. For now, we can say that I just need to get a json file by breaking the data of this input value. And yeah, until i find a good parser for raw text, i still developing remaining sections.